# Problem using a custom OpenCV 2.4.11 build using visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

First Here is what I am trying to do:

I have made a custom build from sources of opencv 2.4.11 (I have some old projects so i wannted to keep using opencv 2 with qt).
To compile it I have used visual Studio 2019. Using the cmake-gui I have set the Platform as x64.
With visual studio I could build all the openCV dlls. So far everything worked fine here.

Here is the Issue I am having:

Now I wannted to test my OpenCV custom openCV build and tryed for that the following CMakeLists.txt script (for using OpenCV with a Camera):

```
    # Root CMakeLists.txt for the overall Pylon project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)    # respect <PACKAGE>_ROOT variables in "find_package"
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

set(OpenCV_DIR  "C:/lib/opencv2411/build")
include (FindOpenCV.cmake)
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include(CMakePrintHelpers)

project(PylonSamples VERSION 0.0)
find_package(pylon 7.2.1 REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}")



add_executable( Main Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( Main PRIVATE pylon::pylon ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

To use it I had to download FindOpenCV.cmake from the internet. Using google I found the code for that in [here](https://github.com/KDE/simon/blob/master/cmake/FindOpenCV.cmake).

Now the generated visual studio code doesn´t work because cmake adds in the linker librarys the .dll files of opencv and not the .lib files.
When i try to compile it I get the following error:

C:\lib\opencv2411\build\bin\Debug\opencv_videostab2411d.dll : fatal error LNK1107:
Invalid or corrupt file: Unable to read at 0x350

Here I can change the name of the library files by hand (changing the .dll files to .lib files) and with that the project will be compiled.

Does anyone know why cmake is adding the .dll-files and not the .lib-files ?
I am not very good in understanding cmake scripts.

Are I am using the wrong FindOpenCV.cmake file ?

I am using cmake version 3.20.0

Comment: Like most others Find scripts. the script `FindOpenCV.cmake` expects OpenCV being **installed**, not just being *built*. You need to install OpenCV (in Visual Studio, use `INSTALL` vcproj). After installing, make `OpenCV_DIR` variable to point to the installation directory.

Comment: Hi many thanks for the reply. I have tried it so i have build the install project. after that I changed "set(OpenCV_DIR  "C:/lib/opencv2411/build")" to "set(OpenCV_DIR  "C:/lib/opencv2411/build/install")". But now cmake tells the following CMake Warning at C:/lib/opencv2411/build/install/OpenCVConfig.cmake:161 (message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has not binaries compatible with your
  configuration. I have built opencv with x64 Plattform and i am using x64 again.

Comment: "I have built opencv with x64 Plattform and i am using x64 again." - Not only platform, but version of Visual Studio should be the same.

Comment: I have looked into the file install/OpenCVConfig.cmake . I think the problem that I have is that the cmake scripts of opencv 2 works only for visual studio until vc12. I am using visual studio 2019 (that is vc15).  I have edited OpenCVConfig.cmake adding the following line: set(OpenCV_LIB_PATH "${OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH}/lib") and now it works.

Comment: just in case it's not obvious: using 2.x is a bad idea. it's way past end of life. nobody support this. whatever reasons you have to messing with it... look for other solutions that don't require necromancy ;)

Comment: no, vc15 is not 2019. it's 2017. 2019 is vc16. that mismatch will be trouble. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B?useskin=vector#Internal_version_numbering

Comment: Yes you are right Christoph but i just use the command set(OpenCV_LIB_PATH "${OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH}/lib") without taking care of the visual studio version that I have. I think you are also right that I should upgrade to newer opencv versions :-)